# Query 2 tables without a join

Tags: postgresql

I am given the schema:

BOOKING (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo)

GUEST (guestNo, guestName, guestAddress)

I an asked to formulate the query for:
List the guest numbers associated with the first name ‘Peter’ having made bookings with unknown dateTo without using an explicit or implicit joins.

My attempted query is:

```
  (select guestNo from GUEST where guestName LIKE 'Peter')
  INTERSECT ALL
  (SELECT guestNo FROM BOOKING WHERE dateTo IS NULL);
```

But this does not return duplicates only at most 1 entry per guestNo, as shown in fiddle where returned values should be (1,1) rather than (1). I thought about using UNION but then this will return guestNo's if dateTo is NULL or name is Peter, i.e. both conditions may not necessarily hold.

Database fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tpzgVMwkQGAHBFxyMkyJvj/17

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you thought about using a subquery instead of a join?

Comment: What @J.Maes said. In addition, when I read "having made bookings", I think `exists`.

Comment: Ohhh so something like : "SELECT guestNo from booking B where dateTo is NULL
AND EXISTS (select guestNo from guest G where guestName='Peter'
            AND B.guestNo = G.guestNo);"

Comment: I wouldn't do it in that order: you usually want to query the smaller table and probe the larger table for the existence of records. There are probably more open-ended bookings than there are guests with first name Peter.

Comment: I tried running the query the way you said but that returned (1) rather than expected (1,1). Think this is because Guest uses GuestNo as primary key so it only checks each guestNo once.

Comment: Everything is a join, even if it doesn't use the word `join`, the syntax you have tried `intersect all` is a join as is `exists` and `in`

Comment: @Charlieface: join is multiset multiplication (possibly combined with a filter), and `INTERSECT ALL` is multiset intersection. Sometimes, you can express one with another, but not always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an almost literal translation from English to SQL, I would write the query as follows:

```
select guestNo
from guest
where guestName like 'Peter%'
and exists (
    select
    from booking
    where guestNo = guest.guestNo
    and dateTo is null
);
```

NB Postgres unlike some other DBMSes doesn't need to have any columns in the select clause! That's ideal in the subselect here as we're only interested in the existence of a record, not in its value).

See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tpzgVMwkQGAHBFxyMkyJvj/17

Comment: I've been using Postgres since '90s and still I learn new things. That's why I love Pg <3 Many people write `... EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ...` or `... SELECT true FROM...` +1 for this

Comment: I agree, as someone who's not super well versed with PostgreSQL, that's a cool tidbit about not needing to actually specify a column list in the `SELECT` clause. Nice, +1.

Answer (score 0):

All these queries will return 1, 1 and optimize to the same plan (for your schema and data):

1. ```
   SELECT  guestNo
   FROM    booking
   WHERE   guestNo = ANY
           (
           SELECT  g.guestNo
           FROM    guest AS g
           WHERE   guestName = 'Peter'
           )
           AND dateTo IS NULL
   ```
2. ```
   SELECT  guestNo
   FROM    booking
   WHERE   guestNo IN
           (
           SELECT  g.guestNo
           FROM    guest AS g
           WHERE   guestName = 'Peter'
           )
           AND dateTo IS NULL
   ```
3. ```
   SELECT  guestNo
   FROM    booking b
   WHERE   EXISTS
           (
           SELECT  g.guestNo
           FROM    guest AS g
           WHERE   guestName = 'Peter'
                   AND g.guestNo = b.guestNo
           )
           AND dateTo IS NULL
   ```

Because `guest.guestNo` is the primary key, this is the same result and the same plan a query with the join would optimize to:

```
SELECT  guestNo
FROM    booking
JOIN    guest
USING   (guestNo)
WHERE   guestName = 'Peter'
        AND dateTo IS NULL
```